Redirect chain occurs when I redirect a page in menu to a subdomain page
I have some pages in www.site.com that I want to redirect them to a subdomain named shop.site.com.
But when I do it, the search engines detecte them as Redirect Chains.
For example the name of the page is "Internet" and the name of the page on sub domain is "internet merchant". The search engine see the "internet" page as Source, and it redirects it first to the address of "***www.site.com/internet***" and then to a final address of "shop.site.com/internet". As a result it sees it as Redirect Chain.
How should I avoid Redirect Chain in this process??
I appreciate if anyone could help.

A subdomain is a different url/domain from the root domain.  Any redirect from one to another is a redirect to a different  url (domain).  There is no getting around it.

...
However, Google treats subdomains as separate sites. While “blog.example.com” and “example.com” may share a root domain, Googlebot will view them as distinct domains and crawl and index them accordingly. This has caused tons of confusion and leads us to the big question:
..

From does-google-index-subdomains

The first thing you should do is make sure that there are not any old redirects that could be interfering with your desired configuration.
Check your configuration files, and revise your question to include copies with sensitive information redacted.
Another place to check is the CMS if you use one. On a WordPress site, for example, you might have a plugin that is creating redirection.
The preferences of any specific search engine are irrelevant in this situation. This is a networking problem.
You are attempting to redirect a URL on one subdomain to a URL on another subdomain. Search engines are reporting a redirect chain. The only possible reason for this is because of an intermediate redirect.
One reason you might see a chain like this, and what I suspect could be the case here, is because of how TLS is being enforced on the first subdomain (www).
GET http://www.example.com/internet -> 301 https://www.example.com/internet -> 301 https://shop.example.com/internet
However, this would only be the case if at least one of the following statements is true:

Search engines previously indexed the http:// version of the site before TLS was enforced.
Other websites might still link to the non-TLS version of the site
If your site has internal links or resources (e.g., images, stylesheets, or scripts) using http://
Your XML sitemap lists http:// URLs

If this is not the case, then the other most likely cause is trailing slash or case normalization:
If a trailing slash normalization rule is applied, the server might be doing this:
GET https://www.example.com/internet -> 301 https://www.example.com/internet/ -> 301 https://shop.example.com/internet
Case normalization would be just like that except you'd have https://www.example.com/Internet -> 301 https://www.example.com/internet
Other options
If none of these are true, then please provide more information about your configuration or stop trying to do the redirect and do one of the following:

Remove the redirect and canonicalize the www. version of the page to the shop. version of the page
Let the www. version return 404 or 410 and request indexing in Search Console for the shop. version

